# VIM: How to check whether the current script is running in a macro?

Tags: vim, macros, vimscript

In a number of cases I have some vim script that I only want to execute when it is not being run in a macro.  For example, in some cases I blink the cursor to remind myself where it is now (which is pointless when run in a macro, and just causes the macro to take 10x as long).

So for these cases I would like to check whether it is running as a macro, and avoid doing the unnecessary operation in this case.  I scoured help for a bit but could not find a flag to detect this.  Is this possible?

Comment: How do you trigger the blinking? If it's a mapping, don't use it. If it's an autocmd, use an event that's not triggered during a macro like CursorHold. Or start every macro with a command that isables your blinking function temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function like `mode()` or special `v:macro_running` variable, and many would argue that those would just encourage bad practices.

What you can do is use the behavior of `feedkeys()`, whose passed keys are usually executed right after the command / mapping, but only at the very end of the macro execution. If you put your long-running commands in there, they will directly slow down normal commands as usual, but only (cummulatively) slow down after the macro execution (and you can usually abort that with `<C-C>`).

#### Example

```
let @q = ',a,b'
```

Instead of:

```
nnoremap ,a aHello<Esc>2gs
nnoremap ,b aWorld<Esc>2gs
```

use

```
nnoremap ,a aHello<Esc>:call feedkeys('2gs', 'n')<CR>
nnoremap ,b aWorld<Esc>:call feedkeys('2gs', 'n')<CR>
```

This will immediately insert the whole `HelloWorld` text inside a macro.